# Form validation breaks widgets alignment

Tags: forms, flutter, validation, flutter-layout, alignment

I've implemented simple form with Flutter and also form validation with message is implemented. There's `TextFormField` with `IconButton` next to it

```
Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      key: Key('new_event_address'),
                      autofocus: false,
                      initialValue: widget.address,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "",
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black26, width: 2.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onSaved: (value) => setState(() => _address = value),
                      validator: (val) => val.length == 0 ? CustomResources.strings["add_event_validation_address_required"] : null,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5)),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add_location_outlined),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
                ],
              )
```

It looks as it should - Text field with icon button:
[image]

But when validation error occurs, icon button is aligned incorrectly:
[image]

I think that's because `TextFormField` changes its position to show validation error message, but `IconButton` position remains the same, so it's not aligned correctly anymore, even if placed in the same `Row` container.

How to fix that? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why not add this icon inside textformfield?

Comment: First, I want visible error message, second - it's default validation layout, is it possible to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,` in your Row and plays on the padding for the icon.

Answer (score 2):

You can only add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,` in your `Row`. It will look like this:

[image]